# Videos taken on the lastest iphones are too bright on Windows 10

Tags: iphone, windows, macos, video

I am working on an issue where videos taken on the latest Iphones are too bright when played on PC's running Windows 10 but the same file plays fine on a Mac.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks
Angelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used options from ffmpeg to convert it as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i input.MOV -vf zscale=t=linear,tonemap=tonemap=hable,format=yuv420p  OUTPUT.mp4
```